# Coverflow with views

Tags: android, widget, gallery, coverflow

I am trying to do a coverflow with layouts, with images I have no problems and works perfectly, the problem is to try to do it with los*.xml.

I have the following errors:

```
 05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774): Unable to find resource: 2130903041
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/prueba1.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030001
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:489)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:274)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at com.example.coverflow.CoverFlowExample$ImageAdapter.getView(CoverFlowExample.java:77)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:745)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:622)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelectionInt(AbsSpinner.java:292)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setSelection(AbsSpinner.java:269)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at com.example.coverflow.CoverFlowExample.onCreate(CoverFlowExample.java:30)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag LinearLayout
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:784)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
    05-14 09:14:56.901: WARN/ImageView(774):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
```

This is the code:

```
    package com.example.coverflow;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CoverFlowExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     CoverFlow coverFlow;
     coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);

     coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

     ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);

     coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

     coverFlow.setSpacing(-25);
     coverFlow.setSelection(0, true);
     coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);


     setContentView(coverFlow);
    }

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     int mGalleryItemBackground;
     private Context mContext;

     private FileInputStream fis;

//     private Integer[] mImageIds = {
////             R.drawable.twitter,
////             R.drawable.centros,
////             R.drawable.seas,
////             R.drawable.estudios,
////             R.drawable.videos
//     };

     private ImageView[] mImages;

     Context context;
        LayoutInflater v1 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View p1 = v1.inflate(R.layout.prueba1, null);

        LayoutInflater v2 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View p2 = v2.inflate(R.layout.prueba2, null);


        LayoutInflater v3 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View p3 = v3.inflate(R.layout.prueba3, null);


     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
//      mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return 1;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      //Use this code if you want to load from resources
         ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
         Bitmap bmp[] = new Bitmap[3];
         bmp[0]=p1.getDrawingCache(true);
         bmp[1]=p2.getDrawingCache(true);
         bmp[2]=p3.getDrawingCache(true);
//         i.setImageDrawable(drawable[position]); 
         i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
         i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); 

         //Make sure we set anti-aliasing otherwise we get jaggies
//         BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable();
//         drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
         return i;

      //return mImages[position];
     }
   /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views 
      * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */ 
      public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) { 
        /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */ 
          return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset))); 
      } 

 }
}
```

It should work to only replace the array of images with the view?
Thanks

Comment: from your error it seems something's missing, have you tried a clean & build (Project->Clean...)?

Comment: my xml layout is simple, only want see on coverflow, one of the 3 test files is this code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="289dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Prueba1"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, the problem is,

You are trying to set XML Layout files as a drawable to your Imageviews.

To make it work, Create View from your XML layout files and then make a Bitmap from it and set these bitmaps to your ImageViews. Then it works..

**Code:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     int mGalleryItemBackground;
     private Context mContext;
     private FileInputStream fis;
     private ImageView[] mImages;
     Bitmap bmp[] = new Bitmap[3];
     Context context;

     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
      LayoutInflater v1 = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View p1 = v1.inflate(R.layout.prueba1, null);
      p1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      // this is the important code :)  
      // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
      p1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
      p1.layout(0, 0, p1.getMeasuredWidth(), p1.getMeasuredHeight()); 

      p1.buildDrawingCache(true);
      bmp[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(p1.getDrawingCache());
      p1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

      View p2 = v2.inflate(R.layout.prueba2, null);
      p2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      // this is the important code :)  
      // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
      p2.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
      p2.layout(0, 0, p2.getMeasuredWidth(), p2.getMeasuredHeight()); 

      p2.buildDrawingCache(true);
      bmp[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(p2.getDrawingCache());
      p2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache     

      View p3 = v3.inflate(R.layout.prueba3, null);
      p3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      // this is the important code :)  
      // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
      p3.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
      p3.layout(0, 0, p3.getMeasuredWidth(), p3.getMeasuredHeight()); 

      p3.buildDrawingCache(true);
      bmp[2] = Bitmap.createBitmap(p3.getDrawingCache());
      p3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache   
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return bmp.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //Use this code if you want to load from resources
         ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

         i.setImageBitmap(bmp[position]); 
         i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
         i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); 

        return i;
     }
   /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views 
      * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */ 
      public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) { 
        /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */ 
          return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset))); 
      } 
 }
```

Comment: I have followed your steps well?
     Context context;
  LayoutInflater v1 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View p1 = v1.inflate(R.layout.prueba1, null);
  Bitmap bMp1=loadBitmapFromView(p1);
  
  LayoutInflater v2 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View p2 = v2.inflate(R.layout.prueba2, null);
  Bitmap bMp2=loadBitmapFromView(p2);
  LayoutInflater v3 = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View p3 = v3.inflate(R.layout.prueba3, null);
  Bitmap bMp3=loadBitmapFromView(p3);

Comment: public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) { 
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, 
    v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
  
Canvas c = new Canvas(b); v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, 
    v.getLayoutParams().height); v.draw(c); 
  return b; 
 }

how set this bitmaps to imageviews?? 

Thankss

Comment: remove this line  i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

Comment: Thank you, but now Null Pointer Exception =(

I think at this line, 
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, 
    v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: ok, Add cast to this?  drawable[0] = ((ImageView) p1).getDrawable();

With this, java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

At the last line

-1000 Thanks for response-

Comment: Bitmap bmp[] = null;
    bmp[0]=p1.getDrawingCache(true);
    bmp[1]=p2.getDrawingCache(true);
    bmp[2]=p3.getDrawingCache(true);
Null Pointer Exception en bmp[0]..... -Thanks for your patience-

Comment: Thanks, no errors, but there is nothing in the coverflow, it appears empty, edit the current code on the post

Comment: The code seems perfect, but not shows me nothing, appears all empty, should modify something in the other class? The project also has the coverflow class, I put?

Comment: why don't you delete the bin and gen folders, clean and build the project and then try

Comment: I try to delete the bin and gen folders, clean and build and run but no show me nothing, empty =( helpp

Comment: i've the next warning: "Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 334 uid 10039"

Comment: Look at my edited answer, How I make a Bitmap from view p1,p2,p3 and also make change in your getView().

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, but I've been thinking that we are not going on the right track, need to interact with the coverflow view and believe that what we are doing is to extract an image from the view, correct?

Comment: It works well, but it is not what I need, if my view is a login, I would like to login from same coverflow. This only allows me to see the Login view, but not the window login. I hope to explain myself well, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Use ViewFlipper for your need. And apply animation on it. Also you have to first mentioned in your question what you need actual. Its help in effort of SO users.

Comment: Yes, I think using ViewFlipper you can achieve what you want.. You have to just modify or define animation for views.

Comment: But the views I need are small, in mode carrousel, as seen in the image that I put in the previous comment

Comment: It would be helpful for you power see it, that became an idea of what you would like to get

Comment: Do if I want to replace the images by coverflow views, it wouldn't create the array of views and display them in some way? Not be very well how to do it

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too. For long time I have tried myself. That's fun. I found in CoverFlow.java, just change somewhere that use/casting ImageView to View. So in getView() of ImageAdapter you can return view as you wish :). Sorry for my English.